# What are the benefits of the z-score interpretation of probit regression coefficients?

Tags: regression, interpretation, logit, probit, z-score

Logit vs. probit is often a big debate. Many prefer logit simply because the coefficients can easily be converted into odds ratios, which are "more intuitive" to interpret than the z-score interpretation of probit regression analyses. 
Of course, many probit users bypass this issue by calculating predicted probabilities instead, but I'm curious to hear if there are any benefits to the raw z-score interpretation. Does the latter have any merits over the odds ratios of the logistic regression, in terms of interpretation of the model?